# when install any package using pip i get error can't import mapping from collection?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pydoc

I work on python `3.10` i face error and i can't solve it .

this error display when try to install new package or

using any `pip` related command

python 3.10 already installed but can't add New Package using `pip`

this error as below got it from command prompt

```
C:\Program Files\Python310>pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .wait import wait_for_read
  File "C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .selectors import (
  File "C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple, Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

so what i do to solve issue please ?

**Last Updated Post**

I delete folder urllib3 from path and execute command below to reinstall again .

but i get error as

```
C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor>pip install -U urllib3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3'
```

this is `collections init.py file`

```
https://pastebin.com/ADc9dV3b
```

so what i modify or on which place i will modify

Answer (score 0):

From Python 3.3 to 3.9, import `Mapping` from `collections` raised a `DeprecationWarning`:

> **DeprecationWarning**: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working

Since Python 3.10, it doesn't work anymore. It looks like you are using an old version of `urllib3` because the `selector.py` file exists only on versions 1.20, 1.21 and 1.22. The current version is 1.26.

Upgrade `urllib3` should solve the problem:

```
[...]# pip install -U urllib3
```

**Update**

Maybe you can remove manually the `urllib3-X.Y.Z.dist-info` and `urllib3` folders in `C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\`. After that reinstall `urllib3`.

Comment: thank you for reply  when  run any command using python as pip install -U urllib3 it give me error message above . if i write any command using pip it will give me message error exactly as above so what i do to solve issue

Comment: any command related to pip give me error above i write pip install -U urllib3 it give me same error as above

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: i update original post

Comment: So restore the folders, the problem is `pip`. Can you check the version file `C:\Users\sa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\_version.py`?. I supposed `pip install -U pip` doesn't work?

Comment: _version.py not exist on path you give me also i use this command pip install -U pip and not working and give me issue error above

Comment: Try to reinstall `pip` manually: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: ok i need to install pip but this error will come again so are there are any tool install pip without command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the file

> (C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\collections_*init*_.py )

and add to the import

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

Just add to collections (.abc)
To get collections.abc